# Odd Core Data error caused by over releasing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios

Occasional reader and first time question asker, so please be gentle :)

I am creating a **Managed Object** (Account), that is being passed into a child view controller where its being set in a property that is retained.

```
Account * account = [[Account alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
AddAccountViewController *childController = [[AddAccountViewController alloc] init];
childController.title = @"Account Details"; 
childController.anAccount = account;
childController.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
[childController release];
[account release];
```

The view controller interface:

```
@interface AddAccountViewController : UIViewController {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * usernameTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * passwordTextField;

@property (nonatomic, retain) Account * anAccount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AddAccountDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldDone:(id)sender;
@end
```

So in code sample 1 I've released the account object because I am no longer interested in it in that method. As it is retained by the **AddAccountViewController** I have an entry in **AddAccountViewController**'s **dealloc** that releases it.

However when I go to delete the object from the **ManagedObjectContext** the app crashes with the following (rather unclear) error:

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
_Unwind_Resume called from function _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow in image CoreData.
```

After much debugging & hair pulling I discovered that if I don't release account in **AddAccountViewController**'s **dealloc** method the app works properly continually and doesn't appear to leak according to Instruments.

Can anyone shed any light as to whats going on? I understand from the docs on properties that those retained need to be released. What have I missed?

***Update to answer Kevin's question***

The code to delete the object from the **ManagedObjectContext** is in the  RootViewController (that holding the child controller)

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that deletes it from the NSManagedObjectContext? And does this happen inside AddAccountViewController or elsewhere?

Comment: `childController.anAccount = account;` this line DOESN'T retain `account`. It copies it to `anAccount`. This doesn't +1 its retain at all, and you will only have to release `anAccount` in `AddAccountViewcontroller`'s dealloc method.

Comment: @Thomas: `@property (nonatomic, retain) Account * anAccount;` Why wouldn't it retain?

Comment: Thomas, it doesn't retain? Its a synthesized set for the property which is declared as `retain` not `copy`.

Comment: Do you save the object context after the account object is created?

Comment: tarasis, what's the backtrace in the crash? Does it happen as a direct result of the call to `-deleteObject:` or does it happen somewhere else?

Comment: Kevin the console output is as above the backtrace is from Problem Reporter and is here: http://pastie.org/1153505. Also adding NSLog trace directly after the `deleteObject:` call is output BUT trace I added after the `save:` object if block isn't output.

Comment: One last data point. If I run the app, add an item to the list, quit the app, restart the app and delete the add object it is deleted and save fine. If I however add another object and delete it, the app again crashes as above. This is what led me to wondering about the release in the AddAccountViewController.

Comment: @Puetras... that retains `anAccount` doesn't it? not `account`... the @property just retains the variable it is setting. To release it you would do `[anAccount release]` not `[account release]`

Comment: Fair Thomas, seems we didn't see / understand what you where pointing out. Your right it wasn't an additional retain and so was incorrectly released at the end of the first code sample. We got confused because you had talked about it copying it too `anAccount`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: It sounds like a bug on Apple's part. Core Data is calling `_Unwind_Resume`, which is (probably) some sort of exception unwind. Exception-unwinding exists on the phone, but (I think) uses the ARM ABI, which uses function names beginning with `__cxa_`. Are you running on the simulator? Which version of the SDK?

There might be an extra release floating around somewhere which is "balanced" when you remove the call to `[account release];`.

"Instruments doesn't show any leaks" doesn't mean there aren't any; last I checked it got confused by cycles (i.e. it wouldn't show a leak if you forgot to un-set IBOutlets in dealloc). I tested with `NSMutableData * d = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:1<<20]; memcpy(d.mutableBytes, &d, 4);`, but an easier test is just `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`.

If you think it's a retain/release issue, I once debugged these by overriding retain/release/autorelease to call NSLog. I then added breakpoints on all of them, set them to run the command "bt", and clicked the autocontinue. Then run the thing that breaks (in my case I think it was just an extra retain), print out the log output,stick it on a whiteboard, and spend half an hour matching retains and releases.

Comment: Indeed removing the `[account release];` at the end of the first block means that the `retain` & `release` in `AddAccountViewController` are properly balanced and the app does no crash when saving after removing an entry from the `ManagedObjectContext`. Regarding the first part, I was running the code on both the simulator & the device and getting that error. The SDK was 4.1GM.

Comment: If removing `[account release];` as described fixes it, then AddAccountViewController is broken (with respect to Obj-C memory management conventions). It's not easy to figure out where it's broken without looking at all the code inside AddAccountViewController which touches the anAccount property or its backing instance variable. (Additionally, prefixing properties/ivars with "a" or "an" isn't in any coding convention I know of, and contradicts the places where Apple uses it.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue ending in a
"Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
_Unwind_Resume called from function _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow in image CoreData."
error message.

My problem was a wrong "cascading" deletion-rule on a relation in the model. With this rule, my top managed object got deleted but still referenced in the code.
After setting the "delete rule" on this relation to "nulify", everything worked as designed.

--> no core data issue...design issue!

Johnny

Answer (score 0):

When ever you delete any managedobject, system will automatically release all reference related to  that object. So there is no need to realese object programatically. Once you delete object there you can not access that object in parent class.

Comment: That's not true.  When a managed object is deleted it's flagged for deletion but it can not release the memory since it violates apples memory management policy.

Comment: I study that NSManagedObjectContext class, i found that when deleteObject method is called , object will be removed from the uniquing tables.